# GetField() return null without reason

Tags: c#, ms-project

my GetField or GetProprety function returns null and I don't understand why 
So this is a small code which returns this problem

```
private void Application_WindowSelectionChange(MSProject.Window Window, MSProject.Selection sel, object selType)
{
    MSProject.Task task;

    string FieldName = Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList[1];
    if (sel.Tasks != null)
    {
        task = sel.Tasks[1];
        var typeValue = task.GetType();
        var typeProp = typeValue.GetField(FieldName);
        var typeGetValue = typeProp.GetValue(task);
    }
}
```

So `task` is never null as it's a condition for my `if`.
`typeValue` gets a value `{Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}`, 
but my `typeProp` and `TypeGetvalue` are `null`.

Comment: `GetField()` returns `null` if the indicated field is not found. If the field does exist but is not public, you'd have to include a `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` parameter.

Comment: Are you sure it's a condition of your loop? The collection itself may not be null but that says nothing of the elements inside it.

Comment: Your title says "gettype() return null without reason" yet your post says that gettype returns `{Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my GetField or GetProprety function returns null

This is because the `GetField` method takes a long ([msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/task-getfield-method-project)), but you are feeding it a string. Instead of using the `FieldNameList` property, which returns the ***name*** of the field, use [FieldIDList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/selection-fieldidlist-property-project) which returns the ***field ID***.

Note: use the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-activecell-property-project).[Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/cell-text-property-project) property to get the value of the first field for the first task in the selection.

Comment: thank for your answer
It's weird, in my case string Msproject.Task.Getfield(MSproject.pjField FieldID) so if I give it my field ID, I get an error message

Comment: Yes, that would produce an error. MSProject is the [Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/), not the parent object of a task. To reference the selected task object use: `Application.ActiveCell.Task`. `GetField` takes a long integer, but you are passing it a _declaration of a long integer_.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection on COM objects do not work as with .NET classes.
As I do not have MS Access installed I can not prove following code.

```
string FieldName = Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList[1];
if (sel.Tasks != null)
{
    task = sel.Tasks[1];
    long projectField = FieldNameToFieldConstant(FieldName, pjProject);
    string value = task.GetField(projectField);
}
```

Sources: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/task-getfield-method-project
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/pjfield-enumeration-project
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/application-fieldnametofieldconstant-method-project

Comment: No, It's not that I need
In fact, you have a parameter that I need to pass
For example task.duration, I'd like to pass duration dynamically and this is why I need extension